# Rsyslog won't forward with JSON template

Tags: networking, ubuntu, syslog

so I'm trying to use rsyslog to accept udp traffic on port 514, apply a json template, and then send it out over udp to port 10514 (this is so my logstash installation can pick it up). I'm running Ubuntu 19.04, and here is my rsyslog.conf file (without default comments):

```
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging

module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

    ############
    # APPENDED #
    ############

template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"@version\":\"1")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
      constant(value="\",\"programname\":\"") property(name="programname")
      constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}

*.* action(type="omfwd" target="localhost" port="10514" protocol="udp" template="json-template")
```

I haven't messed with the default rules file in /etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf, and I have confirmed that traffic is indeed coming in on 514, though nothing is coming through on port 10514. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks ok to me. You might try moving the `IncludeConfig` to the end to check it isn't removing the packet, and replacing localhost by an explicit ip4 `127.0.0.1` or ipv6 address `::1` in case logstash is only listening on one.

Comment: Good idea, but I just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: You can get lots of debug output with `rsyslogd -dn -f my.conf` if you create a minimal config file with just your udp output, and also input module `imfile` [example](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#configuration-examples) to just read a single line message from a file so you can easily track it through the debug.

Comment: @johnbchron Late to the party, but I came across your question while trying to troubleshoot my own "Rsyslog won't forward with JSON template" problem. I tried using your config. Guess what? It solved my problem...